# Sync Gitlab Repository that import from Bitbucket

Tags: import, gitlab, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I already imported some projects in gitlab-ee with Bitbucket Server import.
We are still using Bitbucket as source control and after a month I must updated imported Projects in Gitlab.
How do i do that? How sync gitlab Projects that imported from Bitbucket (without Remove all project and start from zero!!)

I try all of ways that's exist.

Comment: In gitlab, use mirroring with pull option https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks off all
There is no way to sync gitlab project that import from bitbucket. I Delete last Project And import Again, but in this turn remove many branch (merged) and import is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you have a paid GitLab plan or not.

If you pay for GitLab, then the easiest thing to do is to [set up a pull mirror](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/pull.html).

If not, then I suggest setting up your git locally to update multiple remotes following https://stackoverflow.com/a/12795747/4131590

Everyone who contributes to the project would have to set this up separately though.